# Installation/execution of RDkit

Tags: software-installation, python-2.7

I am trying to install RDkit, for that purpose I have followed [this website,](http://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html) and therein is indicated to type:

```
sudo apt-get install python-rdkit librdkit1 rdkit-data
```

Also it can be installed from package manager without any problem.

The program is installed, but when I execute a `script.py`, for example:

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem

parent_smiles = 'c1ccccc1'
rxn_smarts_list = ['[cX3;H1:1]>>[*:1]F','[cX3;H1:1]>>[*:1]O']
molecule_substitutions = {}
```

as `python script.py`

Terminal returns that rdkit is not found. The words are exactly `no module named rdkit`

Any idea what is going bad?

Comment: Did you followed that guide as-is? I think your PATH doesn't contains $RDBASE value. Check it.

Comment: No I just installed the program, what are you talking about?@Redbob

Comment: When you execute that script, it calls for  rdkit, but it cannot find rdkit. At doc you mentioned, there's a topic "Building the RDKit" you must set $RDBASE variable as root directory of the RDKit distribution;

Comment: @Redbob I thought that was on the other way of installing :(

Comment: i havent installed using conda, only typed the line in the post, that is right isn't it?@Redbob

Comment: The way you installed it is not mandatory for the proper functioning of RDKit, but environment variables are important to make it useful to other programs. type `printenv`and look if you have these variables defined there: `RDBASE, LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: @Redbob I have library path defined for another program but nothing about RDkit, what should I do? Thanks for the help..

Comment: I think you should search for help at RDkit forums. Perhaps you'll find something there.